# Jenkins Build Flow plugin with PTC Integrity plugin fails even if jobs are successfull

Tags: jenkins, mks-integrity

**We have below Environment**

**Jenkins cloudbees ver. 1.554.2.2**

**build-flow-plugin version 0.10**

**integrity-plugin version 1.17 (SCM)**

We have created a build flow job, which executes

```
parallel (
{ 
 build("Job-A" , Variant:params.Variant)
 build("Job-B" , Variant:params.Variant)
 build("Job-C" , Variant:params.Variant)
},
 {build("Job-D" , Variant:params.Variant , Environment:params.Environment)},
 {build("Job-E" , Variant:params.Variant)},
 {build("Job-F" , Variant:params.Variant)},
 {build("Job-G" , Variant:params.Variant , Environment:params.Environment)},
 {build("Job-H" , Variant:params.Variant)},
 {build("Job-I" , Variant:params.Variant)}
)
```

*The syntax looks fine, and all the jobs are executed. When executed, I see below status,*

```
Started by timer
Building remotely on d-xxxx999 (windows) in workspace     e:\workspace\Job_1234601\Job-All-Projects
parallel {
    Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-D
    Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-A
    Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-F
    Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-H
    Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-G
Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-I
Build Job_1234601 » Job-A #90 started
Build Job_1234601 » Job-H #89 started
Build Job_1234601 » Job-F #89 started
Build Job_1234601 » Job-D #90 started
Build Job_1234601 » Job-I #89 started
Build Job_1234601 » Job-G #90 started
Job_1234601 » Job-I #89 completed 
Job_1234601 » Job-H #89 completed 
Job_1234601 » Job-F #89 completed 
Job_1234601 » Job-A #90 completed 
Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-B
Job_1234601 » Job-G #90 completed 
Build Job_1234601 » Job-B #87 started
Job_1234601 » Job-B #87 completed 
Schedule job Job_1234601 » Job-C
Build Job_1234601 » Job-C #86 started
Job_1234601 » Job-D #90 completed 
Job_1234601 » Job-C #86 completed 
}
Sending e-mails to: admin@jenkins.test
Finished: FAILURE
```

*From the output it's evident that all the jobs are completed successfully. 
However, I still see that final result is Failure.

Also, I am using build flow plugin for many application builds, all other are working fine.

There are total 5 jobs configured for this applications variants/branches.

Out of which one is successfully running. i.e. output is success.

For other's it's giving above error.
All the jobs in the parent are configured with PTC plugin.

In the jenkins log I don't see any exception.*

***There's one related to PTC plugin,***

> Apr 06, 2016 6:53:11 AM [INFO] IntegritySCM - Failed to shutdown database         connection!
>
> Apr 06, 2016 6:53:11 AM [INFO] IntegritySCM - Database 'x/y/z/jobs/Job_1234601/jobs/Job-I/builds/2016-04-06_06-53-01/IntegritySCM' shutdown.
>
> Apr 06, 2016 6:53:11 AM [INFO] IntegritySCM - java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database 'x/y/z/jobs/Job_1234601/jobs/Job-I/builds/2016-04-06_06-53-01/IntegritySCM' shutdown.
>
> Apr 6, 2016 6:53:11 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase readResponseBody
>
> WARNING: Unsupported transfer encoding:
>
> Apr 6, 2016 6:53:11 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase readResponseBody
>
> INFO: Response content is not chunk-encoded
>
> INFO: Job_1234601 » Job-C #134 main build action completed: SUCCESS
>   flow failed to complete : FAILURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. It was unfortunate that the "Job-E" was typo in the DSL.
The actual name of the job is "Job E".

After doing the changes, everything is OK.

I wonder why Build Flow plugin didn't raise any error for the job which was not present.

I will raise a JIRA & see.